# image upload in home page banner

Tags: image, upload

Root slideshow, home page banner image upload error "error": Disallowed file type.","errorcode":0 magneto 1 , please solve

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command then check again

```
chmod 777 -R pub/media
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the PHP module fileinfo is enabled on your environment (check that in your php.ini, the line `extension=fileinfo.so` exists and if it has a ';' in front of it, remove it and restart the php service).